# SAML ERROR: PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential

Tags: spring-saml

I have integrated SAML 2.0 in my system and I’m using like IDP the file http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml.
Last week my application worked fine, but since yesterday (5th  December 2016) I have an error without doing any modifications in my configuration file.

```
The error is: 
2016-12-06 10:00:07 ERROR: PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=idp.ssocircle.com' |credential entityID='https://idp.ssocircle.com']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2016-12-06 10:00:07 INFO : I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing request: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
2016-12-06 10:00:07 INFO : Retrying request
```

My metada bean is :

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <value type="int">5000</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                             <value type="java.io.File">WEB-INF/saml/sp_sg.xml</value>
                       </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="local" value="true"/>
                    <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                    <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                    <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://localhost:8080/portal_report_sg/saml/discovery"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://localhost:8080/portal_report_sg/saml/login?disco=true"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
         </bean>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="http://88.161.49.14/sg1"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root CA certificate used on SSOCircle has changed yesterday. This probably manifests during artifact resolution, when Spring SAML needs to make a call over HTTPS.

Download the certificate from the [certification authority's website](https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html), store it in file (e.g. ca.cer in PEM format) and import to Spring SAML's keystore with:

```
 keytool -importcert -alias identtrustca -file ca.cer -keystore samlKeystore.jks
```

Certificate example:

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIDSjCCAjKgAwIBAgIQRK+wgNajJ7qJMDmGLvhAazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA/
    MSQwIgYDVQQKExtEaWdpdGFsIFNpZ25hdHVyZSBUcnVzdCBDby4xFzAVBgNVBAMT
    DkRTVCBSb290IENBIFgzMB4XDTAwMDkzMDIxMTIxOVoXDTIxMDkzMDE0MDExNVow
    PzEkMCIGA1UEChMbRGlnaXRhbCBTaWduYXR1cmUgVHJ1c3QgQ28uMRcwFQYDVQQD
    Ew5EU1QgUm9vdCBDQSBYMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
    AN+v6ZdQCINXtMxiZfaQguzH0yxrMMpb7NnDfcdAwRgUi+DoM3ZJKuM/IUmTrE4O
    rz5Iy2Xu/NMhD2XSKtkyj4zl93ewEnu1lcCJo6m67XMuegwGMoOifooUMM0RoOEq
    OLl5CjH9UL2AZd+3UWODyOKIYepLYYHsUmu5ouJLGiifSKOeDNoJjj4XLh7dIN9b
    xiqKqy69cK3FCxolkHRyxXtqqzTWMIn/5WgTe1QLyNau7Fqckh49ZLOMxt+/yUFw
    7BZy1SbsOFU5Q9D8/RhcQPGX69Wam40dutolucbY38EVAjqr2m7xPi71XAicPNaD
    aeQQmxkqtilX4+U9m5/wAl0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNV
    HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMSnsaR7LHH62+FLkHX/xBVghYkQMA0GCSqG
    SIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCjGiybFwBcqR7uKGY3Or+Dxz9LwwmglSBd49lZRNI+DT69
    ikugdB/OEIKcdBodfpga3csTS7MgROSR6cz8faXbauX+5v3gTt23ADq1cEmv8uXr
    AvHRAosZy5Q6XkjEGB5YGV8eAlrwDPGxrancWYaLbumR9YbK+rlmM6pZW87ipxZz
    R8srzJmwN0jP41ZL9c8PDHIyh8bwRLtTcm1D9SZImlJnt1ir/md2cXjbDaJWFBM5
    JDGFoqgCWjBH4d1QB7wCCZAA62RjYJsWvIjJEubSfZGL+T0yjWW06XyxV3bqxbYo
    Ob8VZRzI9neWagqNdwvYkQsEjgfbKbYK7p2CNTUQ
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Spring SAML doesn't use trusted CAs from Java's default keystore in order to keep better control over which certification authorities are trusted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to import to keystore, but I have an error like : The public key of the response and  the Keystore  are not de same.
 In french :`erreur keytool : java.lang.Exception: Les clés publiques de la réponse et du Keystore ne concordent pas`

Comment: It's probably picky about the correct PEM format - I updated the above.